# How do I mount a sparsebundle to a folder rather than an image?

Tags: mount, sparsebundle

I have a encrypted sparsebundle and I want to mount to to a folder in my home directory and not under /Volumes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `hdiutil` command-line utility gives you more flexibility, and is extensively documented in `man hdiutil`. Something like this should do:

```
hdiutil attach -mountpoint ~/myMountPoint mySparsebundle.dmg
```

Comment: can this be made persistent across reboots?

Comment: @ErikAllik yes - but why not ask a general unstinted how to run a shell script at boot time (before a user logs in) or after a user logs in.

Answer (score 6):

You might also be interested in http://blog.marc-seeger.de/2011/02/06/encrypted-diskimages-in-osx/ which explains step by step how to set up auto-mount to the specified mount point:

- run `mount` to identify the disk device (`/dev/diskNsN` usually)
- run `diskutil info /dev/diskNsn | grep UUID` to get the UUID
- use `sudo vifs` to add a line to `/etc/fstab`

  ```
  UUID=whatever-you-noted-before /path/to/mountpoint hfs rw 1 0
  ```
- Add your disk image to your login items to have it automatically mounted on `/path/to/mountpoint` at the next login

Answer (score 5):

```
hdiutil attach /Volumes/ATimeMachine/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library.sparsebundle -mountpoint ~/iPho
```

If this command is successful you should see something like:

```
/dev/disk3              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk3s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk3s2            Apple_Driver43                  
/dev/disk3s3            Apple_Driver43                  
/dev/disk3s4            Apple_Driver_ATA                
/dev/disk3s5            Apple_Driver_ATA                
/dev/disk3s6            Apple_FWDriver                  
/dev/disk3s7            Apple_Driver_IOKit              
/dev/disk3s8            Apple_Patches                   
/dev/disk3s9            Apple_HFS                       /Users/me/iPho
```

where `iPhoto Library.sparsebundle` is on a DroboFS (NAS) and is a 500G "hard disk" image formatted MacOS HFS journaled

Running the `hdiutil` command mounts the image under my home directory. I tired to mount it on top of the original iPhoto Library, but the original was still visible in there after mounting, so I changed the name of the mount point to `iPho` instead. Then I decided it didn't really matter where the mount point was, it would be fine under `/Volumes` as long as `iPhoto.app` knows where it is.

Option click `iPhoto.app` to launch it with a prompt to create a new library, and I did that in the mounted disk image. Then import all photos (previously managed with Picasa under a `~/Pictures` directory tree) on my hard drive into iPhoto, which copies them into the mounted image, which resides on the NAS where it has some fault tolerance because of the DroboFS. This also frees up half the space on my small 500G SSD drive in the MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out the -mountroot option:

```
hdiutil attach -mountroot ~ path/to/image.sparsebundle
```

In this case, it would be mounted to `~/image`.

Also note that with the -mountroot option, if `~/image` already exists, it would automatically append the mountpoint and instead mount the volume to, for example, `~/image\ 2`.

A word of caution: be sure you do not confuse the `-mountroot` option with with the `-mountpoint` option. This would cause the volume to be mounted in place of your home directory!